# UIDocumentInteractionController or QLPreviewController can't zoom PDF on iOS5?

Tags: ios5, uidocumentinteraction, qlpreviewcontroller

I use QLPreviewController to view PDF files in one of my apps. However, ever since iOS5, users can no longer pinch to zoom in/out of the PDF. This is terrible for iPhone users, as they can't read anything.

I have also tried using UIDocumentInteractionController but have had the same problem.

Anyone know what's going on with this?

Answer (score 0):

just check your deployment target and make it as 4.2 and give a trial...